# Changing color for hamburger icon of Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap Navbar in my HTML Code

Default color of Hamburger menu icon is Black in color.
I am trying to change it to while color.
But its is not working

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span id="toggle-icon" class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
```

here is the CSS code

```
.navbar-toggler-icon .navbar-toggler{
    color: #ffff !important ;
}
.navbar-toggle span{
  color: #ffff !important ;
}
#toggle-icon {
  color: #ffff !important ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the Class of Navbar in bootstrap to make the Hamburger icon white
From :
navbar-light to navbar-dark